# Replace e-mail address in existing Mercurial commit data

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a Mercurial (hg) repository with commit data that has wrong (malformed) e-mail address attached to all commits I have pushed. I have direct access to that repository files on the remote server (via ssh). Is there any way I can directly modify the repository files to correct every instance of that malformed e-mail in the commit history?

Comment: @robert: No, there is one more besides me.

Comment: Are you willing to edit his history as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this without rewriting history. Every changeset ID in a Mercurial repository is a cryptographic hash computed from the changeset data. Essentially, changing the email address as just the same as changing contents of one of the files — in every affected changeset.

Do you really need to fix that email? If you do that by rewriting history, you'll end up having something which is essentially a new repository. Your fellow developer will have to abandon his copies of the rep in favor of the re-created one.

To do the actual conversion, the built-in [`convert` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) with the [`--authors` map](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--authors) should help you, I believe. It will create a copy of the repository with fixed author names.

Comment: So if I choose to re-create the entire repository, are there any tools/libraries that would help me with that? Especially preserving commit datestamps etc.